# Display HTML code inside Codename one webbrowser

Tags: java, codenameone

I have some code one HTML, and I want to display this code on WebBrowser, I am using Codename One.

I am tried with this simple code:

```
 protected void beforeWebcams(Form f) {
    WebBrowser browser=new WebBrowser();
    f.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    f.addComponent(browser);
    f.show();
  String htmlcode=""<!DOCTYPE html>\n" +
            "<html>\n" +
            "<body>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<h1>My First Heading</h1>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "<p>My first paragraph.</p>\n" +
            "\n" +
            "</body>\n" +
            "</html>\n";

      browser.setURL(data);
```

the simulator show a blank page.

ideas??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if you just want to show HTML code, and not the web-page, then why dont you use TextArea for showing code.

OR if you want to display as a web page content then you can use this code

`wb.setPage(htmlcode,null);`

Cheers

Comment: Its works. I use the second code and show the content on a web page.